# Relative pronoun where vs which usage

Tags: relative-clauses, relative-pronouns

> The ABC hotel, ______*(a relative adverb/pronoun)* Felix had suggested to me, was really a nice place to stay.

I wonder if both "**where**" and "**which**" are correct here. In my opinion, both "where" and "which" are suitable because the hotel can be seen as both "***a place* that Felix recommended**" *(since the hotel is later referred as "a good place")* and "***an option* that Felix recommended**".

However, the correct answer in a test is "which". Can anyone help me?

Comment: You are confusing *suggest* with *propose*. What you say is absolutely true of the latter. But absolutely not of the former.

Comment: Interestingly, I think that 'where Felix had suggested [staying]', _would_ be unremarkable in casual speech. But 'Felix had suggested the ABC Hotel' really strongly advocates for 'The ABC Hotel,  [the one] which Felix ...'. Stick with the incontestably correct answer for exams.

Comment: @user9989615 An important question for you: did you really intend to mark off the relative clause with commas, thus making it a non-defining one?

Comment: @BillJ Yes, it should be a non-defining one. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I wonder if both "where" and "which" <s>is</s> **are** correct here.

No. **Where** is only an adverb. "Where" equates to "in which [place]" or "at which [place]" both of which are prepositional modifiers.

Only **which** is correct.

In this context, "which" is a relative **pronoun** and the direct object of "suggested".

Compare, *"I stayed at the Ritz, where (at which place) John had booked me a room."* Here, "where" acts as a conjunctive adverb.

Answer (score 0):

> *The ABC hotel, which Felix had suggested __ to me, was really a nice place to stay.*

Of the choices given, only "which" is possible.

The gap notation '__' represents the covert presence of the relative word, which here is required to have a noun phrase as antecedent: "Felix had suggested the ABC hotel to me".

"Where" won't work because it functions as an adjunct of place in a relative clause, typically meaning "in/at some place". But it would make no sense to say *"Felix had suggested in/at the ABC hotel to me".